# Opengl 2.0 with multiple VAO

Tags: opengl, vertex-array-object

I was trying to setup a 2d screen with two layers of drawing

1) a grid made of white solid lines
2) tiles made of colored square

here are my opengl codes:

**setup grid**

```
//glGenBuffers(1, &gridVAO); 
glGenVertexArrays(1, &gridVAO); // **updated**
glBindVertexArray(gridVAO);

glGenBuffers(2, gridVBO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gridVBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gridPos), gridPos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gridVBO[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gridColors), gridColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);


glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**setup tile**

```
// glGenBuffers(1, &tileVAO);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &tileVAO); //**updated**

glBindVertexArray(tileVAO);

glGenBuffers(2, tileVBO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tileVBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tilePos), tilePos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tileVBO[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tileColors), tileColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

**draw tiles**

```
glBindVertexArray(tileVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, TILE_COUNT_X * TILE_COUNT_Y * 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

**draw grid**

```
glBindVertexArray(gridVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, girdVertexCount);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

by keeping only setup+draw grid produces this:
[image: setup+draw grid]

by keeping only setup+draw tiles produces this:
[image: setup+draw tiles]

The VAOs are working properly by themselves.

**However, magic begins here:**

If I do the combination of

```
setup grid
setup tiles

// draw tiles
draw grid
```

It produces this:
[image: error]

Looks like the draw grid codes pick up buffers from tile's VAO. Help Please :D

**update:**

after corrected to `glGenVertexArrays` the same problem still happens

but i found both VAOs are 0

```
cout<<"gridVAO "<<gridVAO<<endl;
cout<<"tileVAO "<<tileVAO<<endl;
```

output:

```
gridVAO 0
tileVAO 0
```

Comment: How come you call `glBindVertexArray` with ids generated by calling `glGenBuffers` ? Looks suspicious... `glGenVertexArrays` maybe ? ;)

Comment: What @NicolasRepiquet said.

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet is correct: Since tileVAO and gridVAO are invalid ids for   glBindVertexArray, these calls throw an error and do nothing. So when you setup your VAOs, grid and tiles both modify the default VAO, which causes this strange drawing behaviour.

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet  i switched to glGenVertexArrays, but the problem still exist.

Comment: gridVAO and tileVAO == 0 right after calling glGenVertexArrays ? What glError say about it ?

Comment: Well, the title of your post says "OpenGL 2.0", and VAOs were introduced in OpenGL 3.0.